# Self-closing TagHelper merges html markup of sibling element

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm litle confused with behaviour of `TagHelper` intoduced in ASP.NET Core MVC. Following this tutorial [A working email Tag Helper](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring.html#a-working-email-tag-helper) we have opportunity to write self-closing tags. According to the article for this purpose we should use attbute `HtmlTargetElement`. Class below is demostrated as an example:

```
 [HtmlTargetElement("email", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string EmailDomain = "contoso.com";
    public string MailTo { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "a";
        var address = MailTo + "@" + EmailDomain;
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "mailto:" + address);
        output.Content.SetContent(address);
    }
}
```

The markup in razor view like:

```
<strong>Support:</strong>
    <email mail-to="Support"/><br />
<strong>Marketing:</strong>
    <email mail-to="Marketing"/>
```

But I have unexpected output:

```
<strong>Support:</strong>
<a href="mailto:Support@contoso.com">
    <span>Another content</span>
    <strong>Marketing:</strong>
</a>
<a href="mailto:Marketing@contoso.com"></a>
```

Why the first anchor tag contains `<span>` and `<strong>` tags content?
Without `HtmlTargetElement` attribute and with closing tags `</email>` in razor view I have correct behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran this same example and was able to produce this same problem.  When debugging, I noticed the TagMode of the output was set to SelfClosing by default.  This is not valid for an anchor tag.  I then set the tag mode for the anchor to StartTagAndEndTag, and the output was generated as expected.

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = "a";

    // ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR CODE
    output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

    var address = MailTo + "@" + EmailDomain;
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "mailto:" + address);
    output.Content.SetContent(address);
}
```

This razor:

```
<strong>Support:</strong><email mail-to="Support" /><br />
<strong>Marketing:</strong><email mail-to="Marketing" />
```

Produced this output:

```
<strong>Support:</strong><a href="mailto:Support@contoso.com">Support@contoso.com</a><br />
<strong>Marketing:</strong><a href="mailto:Marketing@contoso.com">Marketing@contoso.com</a>
```